# Radius of convergence of the sum of two series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I would like to further develop the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150348/), that I summarize as follows:

> **Theorem.** If  $f=\sum a_k x^k$ and $g=\sum b_k x^k$ are power series with radius of convergence $R_f$ and $R_g$, then $f+g$ has radius of convergence at least $\min(R_f,R_g)$ with equality if $R_f\ne R_g$.

My conjecture is that

> **Theorem (conjecture).** If (maintaining all the assumptions of the claim above) $R_f = R_g$, $f+g\ne 0$ and $a_k\ne b_k$ for infinite many $k$, then $R_{f+g}=\min(R_f,R_g)$ also if $R_f=R_g$.

Another shorter formulation could be: if $f-g$ is not a polynomial, then $R_{f+g}=\min(R_f,R_g)$.

> Q: Can someone confirm my conjecture?

Comment: Let $$ f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k, \qquad g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k!}-1\right)\cdot x^k.$$ Then $R_f=R_g=1$ and $a_k \pm b_k \neq 0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$, but $R_{f+g}=\infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you. I adapt the conjecture in the Q excluding the trivial case.

Comment: Basically one can create a variety of counter-example by the following procedure: Let $f, h$ satisfy $R_f<R_h$. Then $g=h-f$ satisfies $R_g=R_f$, and so, $R_h=R_{f+g}>\min\{R_f,R_g\}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee, now I see the problem.

Comment: It's a power series that has a radius of convergence, not a function. So you should say "$\sum(a_k+b_k)x^k$ has radius of convergence...", not "$f+g$ has radius of convergence...". And now it's pretty obvious that your conjecture is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\sum x^{n}$ and $\sum (1+\frac  1{n!}) x^{n}$. This is a counter example.  $f-g$ is entire in this case.

I fact radius convergence of $f-g$ can be any number greater than  the minimum of $R_f$ and $R_g$.